# How can I fix shell error "syntax error near unexpected token 'elif'"

Tags: shell

I have this run as a Shell Script target in my Xcode project

```
# shell script goes here
genstrings -u -a -o en.lproj *[hmc] */*[hmc] */*/*[hmc]
if [ -f "$PROJECT_DIR/build/Release-macosx/UnicodeEscape" ] then
    build/Release-macosx/UnicodeEscape "en.lproj/Localizable.strings"
elif [ -f "$PROJECT_DIR/build/Debug-macosx/UnicodeEscape" ] then
    build/Debug-macosx/UnicodeEscape "en.lproj/Localizable.strings"
fi

exit 0
```

I get this error:

> /Users/aa/Dropbox/Developer/Pandamonia
>   LLC/iPhone/Acey Deucey/build/Acey
>   Deucey.build/Release/GenerateLocalizedStrings.build/Script-00F66869125625D9009F14DA.sh:
>   line 7: syntax error near unexpected
>   token `elif'
>   /Users/aa/Dropbox/Developer/Pandamonia
>   LLC/iPhone/Acey Deucey/build/Acey
>   Deucey.build/Release/GenerateLocalizedStrings.build/Script-00F66869125625D9009F14DA.sh:
>   line 7:`elif [ -f
>   "$PROJECT_DIR/build/Debug-macosx/UnicodeEscape" ] then' Command /bin/sh failed with
>   exit code 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, do not tag it `bash` and `sh`,  you have one shell, type `echo $SHELL` to know which shell you use, or put a shebang at the start of your script (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`)

put semicolons after your commands, including `[` ... `]` which is an alias for `test`. Command terminators are newline, `;`, `&&`, `||` and `&` and are mandatory. You can put several commands between `if` and `then`, so those semicolons are mandatory.

```
if [ -f "$PROJECT_DIR/build/Release-macosx/UnicodeEscape" ] ; then
    build/Release-macosx/UnicodeEscape "en.lproj/Localizable.strings" ;
elif [ -f "$PROJECT_DIR/build/Debug-macosx/UnicodeEscape" ] ; then
    build/Debug-macosx/UnicodeEscape "en.lproj/Localizable.strings" ;
fi
```

Comment: The `;` at the end of the statements are useless null-statements.

Comment: @Jens: except if you don't change line.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please rephrase?

Answer (score 4):

The `then` statement needs to be on a new line, or separate from the if condition with `;`.

Answer (score 3):

You need semicolons before the keyword `then` .

```
# shell script goes here
genstrings -u -a -o en.lproj *[hmc] */*[hmc] */*/*[hmc]
if [ -f "$PROJECT_DIR/build/Release-macosx/UnicodeEscape" ]; then
    build/Release-macosx/UnicodeEscape "en.lproj/Localizable.strings"
elif [ -f "$PROJECT_DIR/build/Debug-macosx/UnicodeEscape" ]; then
    build/Debug-macosx/UnicodeEscape "en.lproj/Localizable.strings"
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue turned out to be incorrect line ending which should be `LF` and not `CRLF`.
This happened because I was working from **Windows**.

You can check this in **Notepad++** by:

> `View` > `Show symbol` > `Show all characters`

and fix by:

> `Edit` > `EOL Conversion` > `UNIX/OSX Format`